# Calling Javascript Function From CodeBehind And Return Value

Tags: c#, javascript, webforms, code-behind

I have some code that looks like this, all in codebehind...

```
var script = "confirm('Would you like to close this order?')";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "CloseOrder", script, true);
```

How do I get the value of whether the user clicked yes or no in the next line? Is it possible that when this script fires that it will return the value and continue on the next line in the codebehind?

Answer (score 1):

```
var script = function(){
    var choice = confirm('Would you like to close this order?');
    if(choice){
        //If the user clicks yes
    }else{
        //If the user clicks no
    }
}
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "CloseOrder", script, true);
```

Comment: Judging by this I assume I have to get it to call a WebMethod to close the order server-side after the confirmation and can't just close it right inside my current C# CodeBehind method directly after the lines listed above in my original question?

Answer (score 0):

Simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/W569P/

change: `var script = "confirm('Would you like to close this order?')";`

to: `var script = confirm('Would you like to close this order?');`

This saves true or false into script based on the yes or no of the confirmation popup.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input although I don't believe you understood my question correctly due to my post. I will edit it.